# How do I fix my trigger query so that the multi-part identifiers can be bound?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a trigger which will allow me to store all the previous data inside specified columns on my Customer table into a specified audit-table once those columns are updated. The fields I'm taking from the customer table and storing are specific, as there are multiple fields on the customers table and I am only trying to store the (*CustomerID, CustomerAddress and CustomerPostcod*e)

**Here is the fields in the Customer table:**

```
   [CustomerID]
   [CustomerName]
   [CustomerAddress]
   [CustomerPostcode]
   [CustomerTelephone]
   [CardNumber]
   [CountyID]
```

I am only trying to take **[CustomerID]**, **[CustomerAddress]** and **[CustomerPostcode]**

In order to store these specific fields I set up an audit table to the best of my ability which will store those fields, but also display auto-generated fields based on the trigger.

**Here is the Audit-Table I set up:**

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Audit

(

Cust_UpdateID int IDENTITY (1,1),
Cust_User char (8),
Cust_Update_Date date,
CustomerID int, 
CustomerAddresss nvarchar (255),
CustomerPostCode nvarchar (255),

CONSTRAINT [pk_Cust_UpdateID] PRIMARY KEY (Cust_UpdateID)

)
```

Here is the trigger query I've set up:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER Customer_Update_Trigger ON tblCustomer
 AFTER UPDATE
 AS

 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Customer_Audit (Cust_User, Cust_Update_Date, Cust_ID, CustomerAddresss, CustomerPostCode)

 SELECT 

 CURRENT_USER,
 GETDATE(),
 d.CustomerID,
 d.CustomerAddress, 
 d.CustomerPostcode

FROM deleted 

END
```

In order to store the data I'm trying to take the fields from the deleted table but every time I do it I keep getting the following error messages:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Customer_Update_Trigger, Line 11
The multi-part identifier "d.CustomerID" could not be bound.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Customer_Update_Trigger, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "d.CustomerAddress" could not be bound.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Customer_Update_Trigger, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "d.CustomerPostcode" could not be bound
```

I don't know what it is I'm doing wrong, I know the field names in the deleted table match the field names in the customer table, but it still refused to process.

Comment: You specified alias `d` in your `SELECT` but did not define it.  Change the `FROM` clause to `FROM deleted AS d` or remove the table alias from the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing an alias for `deleted`, try adding `FROM deleted as d`

```
CREATE TRIGGER Customer_Update_Trigger ON tblCustomer
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO Customer_Audit (
    Cust_User
  , Cust_Update_Date
  , Cust_ID
  , CustomerAddresss
  , CustomerPostCode
  )
SELECT 
    CURRENT_USER
  , GETDATE()
  , d.CustomerID
  , d.CustomerAddress
  , d.CustomerPostcode
FROM deleted as d;
END;
```